# Table not appending to a specific div 'contactsearchtable' in my html

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-objects

I am creating a table and I would like to be able to place it in a specific div element spot in my HTML code.  I keep getting "Uncaught TypeError: tableSpot.append is not a function
at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange" on line

```
tableSpot.appendChild(table);
```

and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  The commented out

```
// document.body.appendChild(table);
```

successfully adds to my document, but I want to be able to hide or show the table, which is why I want it inside a div element.

I have attached part of the js which sets up and 'creates' the table, and the portion of my HTML where I want it to go. ---  I don't think it's of much relevance, but displayChange('div1', 'div2') is just a function that changes the style of 'div1' display from none to block and vice versa for 'div2'.  A slight tangent, but it only works in HTML.  I encounter another error when I try to call it from my js code. ---

```js
var table = document.createElement('table'),
  thead = document.createElement('thead'),
  tbody = document.createElement('tbody'),
  th,
  tr,
  td;
th = document.createElement('th'),
  th.innerHTML = "id";
table.appendChild(th);
th = document.createElement('th');
th.innerHTML = "First Name";
table.appendChild(th);
th = document.createElement('th');
th.innerHTML = "Last Name";
table.appendChild(th);
th = document.createElement('th');
th.innerHTML = "Phone Number";
table.appendChild(th);
th = document.createElement('th');
th.innerHTML = "Email";
table.appendChild(th);
table.appendChild(thead);
table.appendChild(tbody);

var tableSpot = document.getElementById('contactSearchResult').outerHTML;
tableSpot.appendChild(table);

// document.body.appendChild(table);
```

```html
<div id="searchBox" style="display: none">
  <input type="text" id="searchText" onkeyup="doSearch();displayChange('contactSearchDiv', 'searchBox');" placeholder="Please Type or hit Enter" />
</div>

<div id="contactSearchDiv" style="display: none">
  <span id="contactSearchResult"></span>
  </br>
  </br>
  </br>
  </br>
  </br>
  </br>
  </br>
  </br>
  </br>
  <button type="button" id="editFromSearch" style="display:block" onclick="displayChange('editContactDivForm', 'contactSearchDiv');">
            Edit Contact </button><br/>
  <button type="button" id="deleteFromSearch" style="display:block" onclick="displayChange('deleteDiv', 'contactSearchDiv');">
            Delete Contact </button><br/></br>
  <div id="searchList">
  </div><br /><br/>
```

Comment: this sounds illogical, nothing prevents you from displaying a table on demand, you just have to assign it or not a css `display: none;`

Comment: Fix your console errors too

Comment: All is hidden and you cannot appendChild to the string returned by tableSpot = document.getElementById('contactSearchResult').outerHTML - remove the .outerHTML

Comment: I guess what I don't understand exactly is, where in the table being created in my html code?  And how do I access it if I want to work with it later on?

Comment: `tableSpot` is a _string_ (`<element>.outerHTML`) and not an element! And a string doesn't have any `appendChild` function. Append it to the element, not to the HTML string. I guess all you need to do is get rid of `.outerHTML`.

Answer (score 0):

just to help you get off to a better start ...

```js
const
  btShowHide    = document.getElementById('bt-show-hide')
, contactSearch = document.getElementById('contactSearchDiv')
, myTable       = document.createElement('table')
, myThead       = myTable.createTHead()
, myTbody       = myTable.createTBody()
  ;
let newRow = myThead.insertRow()
newRow.insertCell().textContent = 'id'
newRow.insertCell().textContent = 'First Name'
newRow.insertCell().textContent = 'Last Name'
newRow.insertCell().textContent = 'Phone Number'
newRow.insertCell().textContent = 'Email'

contactSearch.appendChild(myTable)

btShowHide.onclick = evt =>
  {
  contactSearch.classList.toggle('noDisplay')
  }
```

```css
* {
  font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size   : 14px;
  }
.noDisplay {
  display : none;
  }
table  {
  border-collapse : collapse;
  margin          : 1em;
  }
td {
  padding : .2em .8em;
  border  : 1px solid darkblue;
  }
thead { 
  background : lightsteelblue;
}
```

```html
<button id="bt-show-hide">show / hide</button>
<div id="contactSearchDiv" class="noDisplay"> </div>
```